# Running custom code after crawling has finished (scrapy)

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to test all of my scraped data after the crawl has finished (percentage of some fields' availability etc). The data is contained in a csv file, so for testing I decided to use Pandas. Is there any way to launch the code that tests the .csv file inside the scrapy spider after Scrapy tells me the crawling has finished? I've tried using extentions, but couldn't get it to work. Thx

```
class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scrapyspider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.example.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com/1/', 'https://www.example.com/2/']


    def parse(self, response):
        for product_link in response.xpath(
                '//a[@class="product-link"]/@href').extract():
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(product_link)
            yield scrapy.Request(absolute_url, self.parse_product)
        for category_link in response.xpath(
            '//a[@class="navigation-item-link"]/@href').extract():
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(category_link)
            yield scrapy.Request(absolute_url, self.parse)

    def parse_product(self, response):
        ...
        yield item
```

Comment: There isn't enough info here to answer this question.  Where is your data?  Are you saving it to a database or just returning an array and looking at it?  What are you using to scrape (BS4, Selenium, etc.)?  Can you include some code from your scraper so people can see what indications it provides that it is finished?  Without amplifying information it is pretty much impossible to give you even a general answer.

Comment: sorry. The post is updated now

Comment: Have you considered running a separate Python script after running the spider?

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy provides you the flow to control the item in `Pipelines`

In `Pipelines` you can verify or can apply any check on the item, if it does not match your criteria or you want to update data depending on some attribute values, you can do there.

More info on `Pipelines` you can read [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html)

Comment: I don’t think this is what the OP is looking for. Item Pipelines are used to handle individual items. I believe the OP wants to analyze the whole item set once the spider finishes.

Comment: Okhay, Then `spider_close` function should do the work `https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html`

Comment: Assuming by that time the serialization to disk has finished. Which might be the case, but I am not certain.